# Speex to FLAC in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, conversion, flac

I've got a speex audio file *(`snd.spx`)*, and I've found *foobar2000* is the only software I can easily convert it to the more-widely-usable format *FLAC (`snd.flac`)* so I can edit it before encoding again to a lossy format. The other software I have just seems to complain about it *(mencoder, ffmpeg, both of which complain they're not compiled to handle speex :( )*

Using the *GUI* is great but clicking manually many times as the files are generated is combersome, so I want to set up a small script to do it for me

Here is where I run into problems, I can't find documentation about how to do this through the command line, calling `foobar2000 /?` brings up the foobar2000 GUI and gives me some non-helpful information

```
Available switches:
  /add <list-of-files> - appends the specified files to the current playlist instead of replacing the playlist content and playing them immediately
  /immediate - bypasses the "please wait" dialog when adding files
  /play, /pause, /playpause, /prev, /next, /rand, /stop - playback controls
  /exit - exits foobar2000
  /show, /hide - shows or hides the main foobar2000 window
  /config - opens the Preferences dialog
  /command:<menu command> - invokes the specified main menu command
  /playlist_command:<context menu command> - invokes the specified context menu command on current playlist selection
  /playing_command:<context menu command> - invokes the specified context menu command on currently played track
  /context_command:<context menu command> <files> - invokes the specified context menu command on the specified files
```

None of these options seem to give me access to the file conversion abilies.

---

Another *speex-to-FLAC* solution using the command line would also be acceptable if it is portable
*(and doesn't require me to compile binaries, I don't have the right environment available to me)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a method to do the conversion using the official tools,

1. Using the *Speex* windows binaries from [**here**](http://downloads.us.xiph.org/releases/speex/) *(`1.1.11win32.zip` worked for me)*
2. Using the *FLAC* windows binaries from [**here**](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/flac/) *(I got `flac-1.3.1-win.zip`)*

You need to do the conversion in two steps to get to get from `.spx` to `.flac` as the official decoder for *Speex* only lets you decode to `.wav` or *raw PCM*

Now assuming you've got `speexdec.exe` and `flac.exe` in the current directory, and `%~d1%~p1%~n1.spx` is the path to the `.spx` file, *(It's `.bat` file trickery to get input args without file extensions)*

```sh
speexdec.exe "%~d1%~p1%~n1.spx" "%~d1%~p1%~n1.wav"
flac.exe -o "%~d1%~p1%~n1.flac" -8 "%~d1%~p1%~n1.wav"
del "%~d1%~p1%~n1.wav"
```

The last line cleans up the intermediate file